# Is there a BeforeCheck for WPF checkboxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Some of the checkboxes on my form should not be able to be checked/unchecked by users. Is there a way for me to cancel the event before the checbox's Check event is triggered?

in winForms it was easy, just

```
public void cb_BeforeChecked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

but I cannot find anything like this in WPF...I figure you can probably do it, just need to do something fancy..

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just set `IsReadOnly="True"`?

Comment: If I could choose your comment as an answer, I would! Except checkboxes do not have an IsReadOnly property, so I used IsEnabled, which works even better, cause it greys out the box if it is no enabled. thanks!

Comment: I posted it as an answer :) Although you're right, I forgot CheckBoxes don't have the IsReadOnly property and you need to use IsEnabled instead

Comment: If you want the "clickable" state to be based on more complex logic, then your event idea affords this, but simply setting `IsEnabled=False` doesn't.  You can fix this by binding `IsEnabled` to some property on the data context/"View Model".

Comment: Pretty funny that a comment recommending a property that doesn't exist get 8 upvotes :) I never see comment upvoting go this high in the WPF tag nowadays

Comment: @Meleak lol I agree, I wish I'd posted it as an answer earlier for the 80 rep :)

Comment: @Rachel: Haha, that would've been even funnier, and way better profit! You're one step closer to the "Pundit Badge" though :)

Comment: Hrrrm that's true, I feel a little surprised that I don't have that one already. Maybe I should work towards it ^_^

Comment: @Meleak well, it pointed me in the right direction. i tried isreadonly, then thought "what about isenabled"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set `IsEnabled="False"`?

Comment: IsEnabled makes the checkbox grayed out.  Sometimes you want it to look that way, sometimes you don't.

Comment: @Bahri: From a UX perspective, if you aren't allowed to check it, it should provide visual feedback.  This jives with the rest of Windows, and consistency is also a good idea in UX.  There's a reason it is the default behavior.  If you don't like the graying, you can also re-style it.

Comment: ya. it is actually more desirable greyed out!  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set IsHitTestVisible="False" to make it not respond to user clicks.  Otherwise you can bind it to a command if viewmodel logic determines whether it is clickable.

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="I cannot be clicked at all"/>
<CheckBox Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" Content="I can be clicked if DoSomethingCanExecute returns true."/>
</Grid>
```

In your DataContext (Viewmodel or otherwise):

```
    RelayCommand _DoSomethingCommand = null;

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DoSomethingCommand== null)
            {
                _DoSomethingCommand= new RelayCommand(
                    param => DoSomething(),
                    param => DoSomethingCanExecute
                    );
            }
            return _DoSomethingCommand;
        }
    }

    public bool DoSomethingCanExecute
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckboxShouldBeEnabled();
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Checkbox has been clicked
    }
```

Comment: mm, I am not using a DataContext. The checkboxes are just in the headers of treenodes, so that tree nodes can be checked/unchecked

Comment: I understand.  You are missing out on a lot of the power of WPF by using the WinForms event driven programming paradigm, however.  You might be surprised by the power of MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit of an overkill, but you could sub-class CheckBox and then override the OnClick() method.

Answer (score 1):

Only setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` just takes care of the Mouse, the users can still use the KeyBoard to tab to the `CheckBox` and change the value.

You should set both `IsHitTestVisible="False"` and `Focusable="False"` to disable the KeyBoard as well

Comment: This is true.  I forgot about the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the check box disabled, and associate a style with the disabled check box, if the disabled look is a problem. As its already pointed in the previous posts, its good to have different looks for different states.